# How to split workbook into separate files based on sheet names?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to save sheets as separate files, but only for sheet names which start with AB***.

The code below does it for all sheet names.

```vb
Sub SplitEachWorksheet() 
  Dim FPath As String 
  FPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path 
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False 
  For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets 
    ws.Copy 
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FPath & "\" & ws.Name & ".xlsx" 
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False 
  Next 
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True 
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True 
End Sub
```

Comment: Additional information : Only sheet name starting AB*** need to split into seperate workbook rest all other sheet not required to split

Comment: You should probably iterate through `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets` not `ThisWorkbook.Sheets` since `Sheets` might, now or in future, include charts (unless you want these split out, which isn't usually useful). Also that will safely allow you to declare `Dim ws as Worksheet`.

Comment: Thank you brax for edit help.... Joffan accepted your point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the rest of it works, here is how to check the name first.

```
Dim ws as Worksheet
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.WorkSheets 
  If Left$(ws.Name, 2) = "AB" Then ' <--- added an IF statement
    ws.Copy 
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FPath & "\" & ws.Name & ".xlsx" 
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False 
  End If
Next
```

Comment: Your code perfectly working fine
 Thank you brax ... Much appreciated for your support